# Free Low-Resolution Backtesting

Tags: backtesting

Basically, I want to start with something relatively simple: Create a total market free-float market cap portfolio in year X and check its performance over the years, where dividends are reinvested using the existing weights. (The difference between this and total market indices is that you don't buy shares of new companies issued after year X).

After that, I want to use some light technical analysis in adjusting the initial weights and test how that affects performance. (Maybe after that also do a yearly weights update based on technical analysis)

Do you happen to know of a way to do this for free? Since I only require low-resolution data I thought it might be possible.
I tried using yfinance but there wasn't enough data.

Comment: A very warm welcome to Quant.SE! What do you mean by "not enough data". It is not clear (at least to me) what kinds of data you are looking for.

Comment: @vonjd Thank you for your comment.
Regarding your question: Well, for starters, I would like to be able to compute the total market cap in year X, in order to weight my portfolio.
Maybe I can get this by taking (yahoo price at year X minus all dividends up to that point) divided by (yahoo current price minus all dividends up to now), times (current market cap)?